# Append image with jQuery producing a 404 error

Tags: jquery

I have a very strange occurring happening when trying to append an image on click. the following is running on http://www.studentsfirstmn.com

```
// submit form
$('.submit_me').on({
     click: function(event) {
         event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
         $.this_button = $(this);
         $.randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
         $.new_button = '<a id="'+ $.randomnumber +'" class="disabled"><span>Submitting</span></a>';
         $.this_button.after($.new_button);
         $('#'+$.randomnumber +' span').prepend('<img src="/content/images/theme/icons/form_submit-loader.gif" align="absmiddle" />');
         $.this_button.hide();
         $(this).closest('form').submit();
         return false;

    }
```

Running this on the live side of my site I get a 404 error when trying to append the form_submit-loader.gif image on click. The strange thing is that I have an exact duplicate of this site code where I do my development, which is behind a .htpasswd, and I get no error loading it on that side. Directly linking to the image in question works fine though http://www.studentsfirstmn.com/content/images/theme/icons/form_submit-loader.gif

Any thoughts?

Comment: if you are using any modern browsers, use its built in debugger and go to something like a "network" section to see whether the images are indeed in the correct path.

Comment: FWIW, **strongly** recommend not adding properties to the `jQuery/$` object willy-nilly like that.

Comment: Picking up on andreas' comment: **All** major desktop browsers now have built-in debuggers -- IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. Some of them are quite good. (Firefox can also be extended with Firebug, a third-party add-on.) All of them will show you network traffic results.

Comment: @andreas Chrome's inspector was how I found out about the error in the network traffic in the first place. Couldn't work without it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How would you write that then? I confess I'm still learning.

Comment: @Withremote: With local variables: http://pastie.org/3687093